# breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbol have been loaded in dll in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll

I write a dll in c++ and another exe file in c++. I inject my dll with my exe in cpp to for example wordpad.exe. but that does not do what i want so i want to debug my dll.
I write both my dll and my exe in one solution and when i put the breakpoint in both of them, my exe start to debug but the breakpoint in my dll get error that said "the breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbol have been loaded".
I do most of the solution in internet and put my dll pdb file in the right folder but it is not working.

by the way I write all of my projects in visual studio 2010.
can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want to debug your dll code after injecting it into wordpad.exe.
You should attach the visual studio debugger to the wordpad.exe process because that's the process where the dll will be loaded.

Comment: i do this with attach to process in debug tab in vs but it does not work.do you mean this?

Comment: Check if your dll is listed in the modules tab of the Visual studio debugger. If it is not listed, perhaps your dll injection is not executing correctly.